# Координаты полигона всего мира Яндекс.Карты API

Tags: javascript, yandex-geocoding-api, яндекс-карта-api

Пытаюсь спрятать все страны кроме России, почти получается, но не выходит попасть в координаты, из-за чего небольшие части карты все-равно видно. Самый близкий вариант получилось сделать в конструкторе, но и там зона все время прыгает, нормально сделать не выходит:

```
  var lineCoordinates = [];
  lineCoordinates.push([
      [ 86.2238, -34.1954 ],
      [ -86.2238, 3.77330 ],
      [ -86.2238, -172.008 ],
      [ -86.2238, 141.586 ],
      [ -86.2238, -32.7892 ],
      [ 86.2238, -34.1954 ]
  ]);
  var a = new ymaps.Polygon(lineCoordinates);
  a.options.set('fillColor', '#fff');
  a.options.set('stroke', false);
  a.options.set('strokeColor', false);
  geoMap.geoObjects.add(a);
```

Пробовал набор координат из GoogleMaps, однако он не подходит

```
lineCoordinates.push([
  [ -85.1054596961173, -180 ],
  [ 85.1054596961173, -180 ],
  [ 85.1054596961173, 180 ],
  [ -85.1054596961173, 180 ],
  [ -85.1054596961173, 0 ]
]);
```

Прошу помощи

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. Речь о сокрытии прочих стран или только ограничении прямоугольной зоны, углы которой вы пытаетесь отыскать? Скрыть все лишние страны можно модулем Регионы. Пример есть в песочнице: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions_districts Найти границы России поможет ответ геокодера на запрос "Россия" - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/

Comment: Регион Россия я выделяю одним цветом, далее рисую полигон с другим фоном, чтобы закрыть остальную карту. Пробовал через модуль, который Вы указали, он закрывает у меня половину карты, ровно по центру заканчивается фигура

Comment: А можете минимальный пример кода предоставить? В уме плохо представляю, что там скрываться пополам может. Например на https://jsbin.com/

Comment: из модуля регионы достал только нужный код, видимо я что-то пропустил
https://jsbin.com/rirecazata/edit?html,output